# How can I create a secure application-database connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

Introduction :
I have a desktop application (.net framework 4.8.2 winform) and successfully connected to MSSQL. But I am afraid that the connection string in the application will be decompiled because it contains all the confidential information of the database. I will use the application I made for a private school project (for students), so I will distribute it.

What I want :
I want to extract data securely from my MSSQL database by connecting to the database via a desktop program.

What I have :
I have a website and hosting provider.

I've seen similar questions to my question on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately, the questions could not be answered.

In short, what should I do? I will continue my research according to the answer given because unfortunately, I am stuck... Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do this is create any web data feeder like API, web service, WCF etc. It is always bad idea to connect your database from client's machine.

Comment: If your users aren't all on the same network then the usual practice is to place the database server behind a web API that supports some form of user authentication, say OATH2 or similar. This issues time limited tokens to the user (when they log in) and the tokens are then used for authentication by being used on each API call. Locally the application just requires the web connection path. The token is stored in memory and not saved.